# Weird scroll behaviour in Pages 09

Tags: pages

this really bemuses me. i'm using pages 09 (version 4.1) on osx 10.9.5. when i terminate a scroll downward, the document makes a little "jump" to the right. this is maybe hard to visualize, so i made a gif:

http://gfycat.com/ExemplaryAdoredAntelope

also notice in the gif, there's a little gray area to the right of the document: when i resize the window the document grows or shrinks accordingly (zoom is set to "Fit Width"), but the gray area stays there.

this behaviour occours with some documents/windows, but not others. i tried to close/reopen the affected windows, and even quit/restart pages, to no avail.

how can i fix/prevent/workaround this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. In the bottom left corner of the window, click on the zoom control and select `100%` (or any fixed value).
2. Click again and select `Fit Width`.
3. Scroll is fixed.

Comment: @jherran please explain the rationale behind your editing